# Multiple event files created for the same run of tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow and creating a summary every 100 steps. The problem is that after about an hour from start tensorflow stops writing the summary to the same event file and starts a second event file. The main problem with this is that it causes my tensorboard graph to think I've started training from step 0 again (as can be seen in the attached image).

[image: image showing the multiple event files problem in tensorboard]

Any ideas?
The code from my main loop:

```py
if step % int(FLAGS.summary_interval) == 0:
    _, summary = sess.run([apply_gradient_op, summary_op], 
                      feed_dict={images: input_images, labels: input_labels})
    train_writer.add_summary(summary, step)
    train_writer.flush()
else:
   sess.run([apply_gradient_op], 
            feed_dict={images: input_images, labels: input_labels})
```